# structured streaming with Spark 2.0.2, Kafka source and scalapb

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, scalapb

I am using structured streaming (Spark 2.0.2) to consume kafka messages. Using scalapb, messages in protobuf. I am getting the following error. Please help..

> Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException:  is
>   not a term    at
>   scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi$class.asTerm(Symbols.scala:199)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asTerm(Symbols.scala:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.constructParams(ScalaReflection.scala:811)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.constructParams(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.getConstructorParameters(ScalaReflection.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.getConstructorParameters(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:582)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:460)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:592)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:583)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:252)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:583)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:425)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:61)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:274)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:47)
>     at PersonConsumer$.main(PersonConsumer.scala:33)    at
>   PersonConsumer.main(PersonConsumer.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

The following is my code ...

```
object PersonConsumer {
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
  import com.trueaccord.scalapb.spark._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
  import com.example.protos.demo._

  def main(args : Array[String]) {

    def parseLine(s: String): Person =
      Person.parseFrom(
        org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(s))

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("spark session example")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").option("subscribe","person").load()

    val ds2 = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]

    val ds3 = ds2.map(str => parseLine(str)).createOrReplaceTempView("persons")

    val ds4 = spark.sqlContext.sql("select name from persons")

    val query = ds4.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()
    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line with `val ds3` should be:

```
val ds3 = ds2.map(str => parseLine(str))

sqlContext.protoToDataFrame(ds3).registerTempTable("persons")
```

The RDD needs to be converted to a data frame before it is saved as temp table.

Answer (score 0):

In Person class, gender is a enum and this was the cause for this problem. After removing this field, it works fine. 
The following is the answer I got from  Shixiong(Ryan) of DataBricks.

The problem is "optional Gender gender = 3;". The generated class "Gender" is a trait, and Spark cannot know how to create a trait so it's not supported. You can define your class which is supported by SQL Encoder, and convert this generated class to the new class in `parseLine`.